# Étale homotopy equivalent varieties are deformation equivalent

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p>0$.

Let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be étale simply-connected smooth proper varieties over $k$. Assume there is an isomorphism between the prime-to-$p$ étale homotopy types of $V_1$ and $V_2$ respecting the total $l$-adic Chern classes of the tangent bundle for all $l\neq p$.

Does there exist a connected scheme $S$ of finite type over $k$ and a proper flat morphism $\mathcal{V}\to S$ having $V_1$ and $V_2$ as closed fibers?

Comment: Why should that be true?

Comment: This is the only deformation invariant I am aware of so I wonder if it is sufficient. Picard group, Kodaira dimension, Hodge numbers, pro-$p$ étale stuff are not necessarily deformation invariant. In characteristic $0$ there are more deformation invariants but there is still something weird going on with complex surfaces (Manetti, Catanese etc.).

Comment: This is my point. After the work of Manetti and Catanese and others we have simply connected topological manifolds with two complex structures that are not deformation equivalent. I would expect that their examples may be adapted to characteristic p to give a negative answer to your question, but I'm not an expert in finite characteristic issues.